# How to delete a git repo locally without deleting untracked files

Tags: git, shell

Here is the situation. I'm in the directory `~/tests`. Under this directory, I have many repos. And after I just cloned a new repo, I forgot to `cd` into the repo before creating any branches, push, merge and other stuff. So I accidentlly initialized `~/tests` "root" directory as a git repo, and added some remotes and fetched from the remotes here. Now I just want my `~/tests` directory to be back to what it was, i.e. not a repo, and without deleting anything else in `~/tests` directory, because I have a lot of other important files and repos here.
How can I restore `~/tests` back to a normal direcotry without hurting anything inside.

I have tried `git remote -v` and `git remote rm origin` to removed remotes, but still this is a git repo.

Answer (score 1):

As [the manual page for the "git init" command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) says, initialising a git repository in an existing directory just creates a directory called ".git".

All of git's "database" is stored in that directory, so to go back to being a plain directory, all you need to do is delete that sub-directory.

It might be hidden by default, but a simple `rm -rf ~/tests/.git` will work. Obviously, make 100% sure you're deleting the right thing first! (You could of course move or rename the directory instead of deleting it, to give you a chance to change your mind.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this. But the files I have pulled down still exist in the `tests` directory. I want to remove all the pulled stuff, but not remove anything that already exist before I initialize the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `.git` directory inside `~/tests` and it will just be a regular directory rather than a git repo.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks, I tried this. But the files I have pulled down still exist in the tests directory. I want to remove all the pulled stuff, but not remove anything that already exist before I initialize the repo.

I would be very careful, and:

- create a `testsbis` folder
- move the existing `tests` repositories to it
- delete `tests` (which will delete the `.git` folder and all the fetched files)
- rename `testsbis` to `tests`